# C# Deserilize from xml to object (<result xmlns=''> was not expected.)

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization

I try to desalinize from XML to object. When i try to execute this code i get this inner exception get error message  **was not expected.**. Please help me. Thank you for all reply.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <status>
         <interfaceId>shop.shipping.segment.get</interfaceId>
         <systemStatus>OK</systemStatus>
         <message>OK</message>
         <requestId>714a4983-555f-42d9-aeea-89dae89f2f55</requestId>
         <requests>
            <id>1</id>
            <kbnId>1</kbnId>
         </requests>
    </status>
    <tns:shopMngApiResponse xmlns:tns="http://rakuten.co.jp/rms/mall/shop/mng/api/model/resource">   
        <resultCode>N000</resultCode>
        <resultMessageList>
            <resultMessage>
                <code>N000</code>
                <message>Succeeded.</message>
            </resultMessage>
        </resultMessageList>
        <result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="tns:soryoKbnResourceModel">
            <soryoKbnList>
                    <soryoKbn>
                        <shopId>202317</shopId>
                        <kbnId>1</kbnId>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>test name 1</name>
                    </soryoKbn>
                    <soryoKbn>
                        <shopId>202317</shopId>
                        <kbnId>2</kbnId>
                        <id>7</id>
                        <name>test name 2</name>
                    </soryoKbn>
                </soryoKbnList>
          </result>
     </tns:shopMngApiResponse>
</result>
```

Source Code: https://app.box.com/s/mmuk2ndkmz4llb71ryw81rpzca9mrmge

Comment: You missed ending tag for <result> in this XML file. Add </result> after </tns:shopMngApiResponse> tag

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue, else we're just guessing.

Comment: One technique you might find useful for debugging this is to create the objects and serialise them and see where the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing into the "result"- object set the property as following:

```
 [XmlElement(ElementName = "result", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
 public YOURRESULTOBJECT result { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank Mr. Alexis Peters for your reply but it still error. Here is my source code https://app.box.com/s/mmuk2ndkmz4llb71ryw81rpzca9mrmge please help me.